# VLC Playlist with Settings

Tags: vlc-media-player, playlists, shuffle

Is it posible to store playlists in VLC Player with e.g. shuffle and repeat selected.

I have a playlist where I would rather have it start with a random track than having it start with the first tract - and preferably it should also repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a modified version of VLC media player that shuffles only for playlists, while at the same time it plays other files sequentially.
It can be downloaded from [Github](https://github.com/Zemanm17/vlc-1/tree/playlist_shuffle)

Answer (score -1):

Go to Tool - Preferences- Left below Check button "All".

Search on left - Playlist - check or uncheck ' Play files randomly forever' and save.

[Link](http://findsolutionz.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-shuffle-songs-in-vlc-media-player.html)

Comment: That will change the global settings - not the settings for the specific playlist. I would like to store the settings with the specific playlist